# Custom action bar not working in edittext on HTC sense

Tags: android, htcsense

I have an app that uses a custom action bar on an EditText window. This works fine on vanilla Jellybean 4.1 and 4.2, but on an HTC One X+ it seems HTC Sense is getting in the way. This is what I see on vanilla JB:

[image: JB action bar]
<sub>(source: [sr20.org](http://www.sr20.org/jb.png))</sub>

So I have my custom action bar with style buttons (I, B, U).

And this is what I see on HTC. The action bar has not been replaced with mine, instead there is a Sense version of the copy/paste popup.

[image: HTC copy/paste]
<sub>(source: [sr20.org](http://www.sr20.org/htc.png))</sub>

Any ideas on how I can persuade the EditText to behave like the Android API says it should?